# Permission denied for relation stl_load_errors on Redshift Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, amazon-redshift-serverless

I use Amazon Redshift Serverless and Query editor(v2) and I'm having trouble with user permissions.
The following error occurred when importing data(.csv) in S3.

```
ERROR: Load into table 'x' failed. Check 'sys_load_error_detail' system table for details.
```

Therefore, I executed the command `Select * From stl_load_errors` to check the error, but it did not work well.

```
ERROR: permission denied for relation stl_load_errors
```

I checked my user permissions using `select * from pg_user;`and they are presented as follows.
However, I don't see any problem, what is the problem?
(I use hoge.)

| usename | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | usecatupd | passwd | valuntil | useconfig |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rdsdb | 1 | true | true | true | ******** | infinity | NULL |
| hoge | 101 | true | true | false | ******** | NULL | NULL |

I have tried to look at the query in the Amazon Redshift Serverless (Preview) dashboard under "Query and Database Monitoring", but could not find any details about the error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
select * from sys_load_error_detail
```

Answer (score 11):

AWS Redshift serverless is not exposing the stl_load_errors table

Perhaps you should try SYS_LOAD_HISTORY and SYS_LOAD_ERROR_DETAIL.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/serverless-monitoring.html
You can't query STL, STV, SVCS, SVL, and some SVV system tables and views with Amazon Redshift Serverless, except the following:
...see link above....