# COPYing of JSON files from S3 to Redshift serverless times out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

**Problem:** The query below worked fine a few days ago and took only a few seconds to execute (it's only 20 small JSON files). However, now it times out after 45min. I haven't touched redshift or the query since then.

**Question**: How can I identify the root cause for the timeout?

**What I tried:**

- Using AWS Redshift Monitoring GUI I cancelled all running queries.
- According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73859105/2135504 I can only access two system tables from redshift which didn't provide any insight.
- AFAIK redshift doesn't log anything to cloudwatch.
- AFAIK I can also not increase verbosity of the SQL query.

```sql
COPY staging_songs
FROM 's3://my-bucket/song_data/A/A/A/'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::my:role/my-redshift-service-role'
JSON 'auto'
STATUPDATE OFF
MAXERROR 1
COMPUPDATE OFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is timing out?  The connection?  The statement?  If the statement what timeout limit is being encountered?

Have you checked for locks on the target table?  If it is exclusively locked by some other transaction then your statement cannot move until this lock is released.  There may be another transaction that is clogging up the works.

What messages did you receive before the timeout?  Did the COPY complete and the hang occur on the COMMIT?

Can you copy the info into another (temp) table and ensure that the files and commands are good?

Basically you want to divide the steps in play and test each step independently.  Connection, statement, commit, access to S3 files, return of statement results, etc.